# Импорт БД из phpmyadmin в Opencart магазин

Tags: phpmyadmin, opencart, mysql

У меня на локальном компьютере есть магазин openCart. Я из `phpMyAdmin` экспортирую 10 таблиц (такие как `eh_product_description, eh_product_to_category` и т.д.). Получается sql файл размером порядка 23МБ. Потом я этот файл опять же через `phpMyAdmin` импортирую в openCart магазин уже на моем хостинге. После импорта (там порядка 6.000 товаров, 600 с чем-то категорий) начинает очень сильно виснуть сайт, страницы открываются секунд по 10.

Причем есть подобный файл с теми же таблицами (чуть меньше, на 16 МБ). Если его импортировать, то все нормально со скоростью. А разница в размерах всего 7 МБ. Не может же это быть причиной...

Вопрос: почему может виснуть сайт в этом случае?

Comment: и там, и там типовые sql файлы экспорта из phpmyadmin. 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...
INSERT INTO ...
и так для каждой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причин может быть несколько:

- Включена опция подсчета количества товаров в категориях.
- Непроставлены индексы.
- Если стоит FilterPro - у старых версиях есть бажина, которая тянет ВСЕ товары из базы независимо от категории.
- Медленный хостинг.
- Ну и еще куча всякого барахла, хз.

Если у вас есть возможность, то посмотрите лог медленных SQL запросов. В крайнем случае попросите эти логи у хостера.